# OO design,  table design

Tags: c++, design-patterns, object

Design table with wood or steel meterial. I have following designed, which is better and why? Or any better suggestion design?

design 1 :

```
class Meterial{
public:
  void virtual info()=0;
};

class Wood:public Meterial{
public:
  void info();
};

void Wood::info(){
  cout<<"wood"<< " ";
}

class Steel:public Meterial{
public:
  void info();
};

void Steel::info(){
  cout<<"steel"<< " ";
}




class Furniture{
  void virtual info()=0;
};

class Table:public Furniture{
private:
  Meterial * _meterial;
public:
  Table(Meterial * m);
  void info();
};

Table::Table(Meterial * m){
  _meterial= m;
}


void Table::info(){
  _meterial->info();
  cout<< " table " << endl;
}

int main(){
  Table * wood_table=new Table(new Wood());
  Table * steel_table=new Table(new Steel());
  wood_table->info();
  steel_table->info();
}
```

design 2:

```
class Meterial{
public:
  virtual void info()=0;
};

class Wood:public Meterial{
public:
  void info();
};

void Wood::info(){
  cout<<" wood " << " ";
}

class Steel:public Meterial{
public:
  void info();
};

void Steel::info(){
  cout<<" Steel " << " ";
}



class Furniture{
public:
  virtual void info()=0;
};

class Table:public Furniture{
public:
  void info();
};

void Table::info(){
  cout<<" table "<< endl;
}

class WoodTable:public Wood,public Table{
public:
  void info();
};

void WoodTable::info(){
  Wood::info();
  Table::info();
}


class SteelTable:public Steel,public Table{
public:
  void info();
};

void SteelTable::info(){
  Steel::info();
  Table::info();
}



int main(){
  WoodTable *woodTable = new WoodTable();
  SteelTable *steelTable = new SteelTable();

  woodTable->info();
  steelTable->info();
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Is the form of the table different depending on what it is made of?  If not, you're doing way too much work.  `enum Material { Wood, Steel };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use inheritance when you have a very specific reason to, or when all other options are not better nor worse. Never inherit for reuse.

Does material have any *behaviour* that can change dynamically? Can the table's material change at runtime? If the answer is yes to either of these then you'll likely need runtime polymorphism and inheritance. Your first design is then a good step in the right direction. Your second design, however, is risky and brings little to the table (and pardon the pun). Multiple inheritance? Why? You should have a very specific, solid reason to use multiple inheritance.

Another design alternative is to use compile-time polymorphism.

```
struct wood { };
struct steel { };

template<class M>
struct table { };

// ...
table<wood> wood_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of the difference between "is a" and "has a". A table *has* a material property, a table itself isn't a material. I would go with the first one.

Comment: But isn't a wooden table just a piece of wood that has a table shape? The piece of wood existed before it got table-shaped and will exist afterwards, so "being table shaped" must be a property, right? Even a mutable one: With the right tools, you can keep the same wooden object, but give it a different shape.

Comment: That pretty much falls over once you have a glass-topped table with a wooden border and steel legs :)

Comment: @nikie: it's a *piece* of wood, but a table isn't a material, it's a discrete physical object. Wood in these designs is a Material, a Table isn't a Material, so a Table can't be a Wood. If Wood was designed to mean PieceOfWood then maybe you could consider a Table also to be a Wood. Of course normally it's several pieces.